# Is it possible to have identical project but varying Cypress version?

Tags: cypress

here are the current steps I am doing thus far,

1. In my current Cypress git remote branch, it is set to `v9.5.4` (Branch name is SI)
2. we are planning to test out v10.0.3 so I checked out to a new **local branch** then migrated the current project to `v10.0.3`
3. I pushed the newly migrated project branch to **remote** and named it **SI-v10**
4. I checked-out **back to SI** which I assume to remain v9.5.4
5. When I try to run the project, it is behaving and assuming that the current project is v10.0.3 by looking for folders that were not yet present prior to the upgrading of Cypress.

Is there a more realistic / possible way to have different versions of Cypress in a project which I can just check-out to?

Comment: You'll need to reinstall dependencies when you switch branches, assuming `node_modules/` isn't under version control.

Comment: I see, if my understanding is correct, every time I switch branches, I need to reinstall the associated Cypress version for that branch. Unless I remove `node_module` in `.gitignore`

Comment: It's not just about Cypress - _in general_ different branches can have different dependencies.